How to Customize Text in SwiftUI Picker with Custom Font and Color?
I'm trying to customize the text in a SwiftUI Picker to use a specific custom font and color. However, I'm having trouble getting the custom styles to apply correctly. Here is my current implementation:
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

// Enums for Filter and Sort Options
enum EventFilter: String, CaseIterable, Identifiable {
    case all = "All"
    case liked = "Liked"
    case attending = "Attending"
    case pendingApproval = "Pending Approval"

    var id: String { self.rawValue }
}

enum EventSort: String, CaseIterable, Identifiable {
    case date = "Date"
    case title = "Title"

    var id: String { self.rawValue }
}

// Color Utils for Custom Colors
struct ColorUtils {
    static let darkPurple = Color(red: 51 / 255, green: 0 / 255, blue: 102 / 255)
    static let lightPurple = Color(red: 245 / 255, green: 240 / 255, blue: 255 / 255)
}

// Filter and Sort View
struct FilterSortView: View {
    @Binding var selectedFilter: EventFilter
    @Binding var selectedSort: EventSort

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Picker("Filter", selection: $selectedFilter) {
                ForEach(EventFilter.allCases) { filter in
                    Text(filter.rawValue)
                        .font(.custom("samble", size: 16))
                        .foregroundColor(ColorUtils.darkPurple)
                        .tag(filter)
                }
            }
            .pickerStyle(MenuPickerStyle())

            Picker("Sort", selection: $selectedSort) {
                ForEach(EventSort.allCases) { sort in
                    Text(sort.rawValue)
                        .font(.custom("samble", size: 16))
                        .foregroundColor(ColorUtils.darkPurple)
                        .tag(sort)
                }
            }
            .pickerStyle(MenuPickerStyle())
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

// Preview
struct FilterSortView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    @State static var selectedFilter: EventFilter = .all
    @State static var selectedSort: EventSort = .date

    static var previews: some View {
        FilterSortView(selectedFilter: $selectedFilter, selectedSort: $selectedSort)
            .previewLayout(.sizeThatFits)
    }
}

Problem:
I can't get the custom font and color to apply correctly to the text in the Picker. The styles seem to be ignored.

Are you trying to style just the picker button that opens the menu, or also the options in the menu? The latter is not possible - you'd have tomato your own picker.

SwiftUI picker are not really customisable. You need to go through UIKit
